# Retrofit handle Flux return type

Tags: java, spring-boot, retrofit, retrofit2, flux

How to hanle Flux return type in retrofit?

**EndPointApi**

```
public interface DataEndPointApi {
   @GET( "ap1/v3/data")
   Flux<Data> getAllData(@Query( "dataType") String dataType);
}
```

**RetroRestAdapter**

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

RestAdapter retrofit = new RestAdapter.Builder()
         .setEndpoint( "http://localhost:8080" )
         .setConverter( new JacksonConverter( this.objectMapper ) )         
         .build();
```

**Caller**

```
DatasourceEndPointApi datasourceEndPointApi;
Flux<Data> dataFlux = this.dataEndPointApi.getAllData( "GREETING" );
```

I'm getting below error

**Error**

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `reactor.core.publisher.Flux` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (retrofit.ExceptionCatchingTypedInput$ExceptionCatchingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at retrofit.RetrofitError.conversionError(RetrofitError.java:33)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:383)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy153.getAllDatasource(Unknown Source)
    at
```

So, how can I handle Flux return type in Retrofit?

Comment: You would need to use Retrofit2 instead of Retrofit1, and you need to define your own CallAdapterFactory that handles Flux type.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks for the comment. Can you please provide one example? or link to an example?

Comment: Technically you need this thing: https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-reactor-adapter but I do not know if it is up to date.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce may be the best is to use spring webclient instead of retrofit https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/